# Set android camera to send gray scale images

Tags: java, android, android-camera

Can the android camera be programmatically set to send gray scale images.
I'm not asking about conversion after the images have been received, I'm asking for a way to programmatically set it like we do with fps, resolution etc.

Answer (score 0):

Are you talking about the built in camera app (via an intent) or inside your app?

If it's the built in camera app, i don't think it's possible, and even if it was , you can't assume it will work the same on all devices, since many of them have customized camera apps.

About camera within your app, yes, you can do it, and there are examples out there how to do show things on the camera based on its content , like [**this one**](http://developer.sonymobile.com/2013/02/14/get-started-with-opencv-on-android-tutorial-code-example/)